# Multiprocessing error : can't import module

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm getting an error message that i'm unable to tackle. I don't get what's the issue with the multiprocessing library and i don't understand why it says that it is impossible to import the build_database module but in the same time it executes perfectly a function from that module.

Could somebody tell me is he sees something. Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
prepare(preparation_data)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
        prepare(preparation_data)
'__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
  File "C:\Users\Comp3\Desktop\User\Data\main.py", line 4, in <module>
         '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
import database.build_database
  File "C:\Users\Comp3\Desktop\User\Data\main.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError    : import database.build_database
NImportErroro module named build_database:
No module named build_database
```

This is what i have in my load_bigquery.py file:

```
# Send CSV to Cloud Storage 
def load_send_csv(table):
    job = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print '[' + table + '] : job starting (' + job + ')'
    bigquery.send_csv(table)    


@timer.print_timing  
def send_csv(tables):
    jobs = []

    build_csv(tables)

    for t in tables:
        if t not in csv_targets:
            continue

        print ">>>> Starting " + t

        # Load CSV in BigQuery, as parallel jobs
        j = multiprocessing.Process(target=load_send_csv, args=(t,))
        jobs.append(j)
        j.start()

    # Wait for jobs to complete
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
```

And i call it like this from my main.py :

```
bigquery.load_bigquery.send_csv(tables)
```

My folder is like this:

```
src
|   main.py
|
├───bigquery
│   │   bigquery.py
│   │   bigquery2.dat
│   │   client_secrets.json
│   │   herokudb.py
│   │   herokudb.pyc
│   │   distimo.py
│   │   flurry.py
│   │   load_bigquery.py
│   │   load_bigquery.pyc
│   │   timer.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   __init__.pyc
│   │   
│   │   
├───database
│   │   build_database.py
│   │   build_database.pyc
│   │   build_database2.py
│   │   postgresql.py
│   │   timer.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   __init__.pyc
```

That function works perfectly if i execute load_bigquery.py alone but if i import it into main.py it fails with the errors given above.

UPDATE :

Here are my import, maybe it might help:

```
main.py
         import database.build_database
         import bigquery.load_bigquery
         import views.build_analytics
         import argparse
         import getopt
         import sys
         import os

load_bigquery.py
         import sys
         import os
         import subprocess
         import time
         import timer
         import distimo
         import flurry
         import herokudb
         import bigquery
         import multiprocessing
         import httplib2

bigquery.py
         import sys
         import os
         import subprocess
         import json
         import time
         import timer
         import httplib2

         from pprint              import pprint
         from apiclient.discovery import build
         from oauth2client.file   import Storage
         from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
         from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
         from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
         from oauth2client.tools  import run
         from apiclient.errors    import HttpError
```

Maybe the issue is with the fact that load_bigquery.py imports multiprocessing and then main.py imports load_bigquery.py ?

Comment: You should add a minimal example of your own code that can reproduce the issue. It will make it easier for someone to help solve the problem.

Comment: You need to have an ``__init__.py`` file in ``src/bigquery`` so that python knows it is a package.

Comment: I have an empty `__init__.py` in my bigquery folder

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the `__init__.py` inside `src/bigquery/`.  So your source folders should be:

```
> src/main.py
> src/bigquery/__init__.py
> src/bigquery/load_bigquery.py
> src/bigquery/bigquery.py
```

The `__init__.py` just needs to be empty and is only there so that Python knows that bigquery is a [Python package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

UPDATED: Apparently the `__init__.py` file is present.  The actual error message talks about a different error, which is it cannot import `database.build_database`.

My suggestion is to look into that.  It is not mentioned as being in the src folder...

UPDATE 2: I think you have a clash with your imports.  Python 2 has a slightly fuzzy relative import, which sometimes catches people out.  You have both a package at the same level of `main.py` called `database` and one inside `bigquery` called `database`.  I think somehow you are ending up with the one inside `bigquery`, which doesn't have `build_database`.  Try renaming one of them.

Comment: I have an empty `__init__.py` in my bigquery folder

Comment: You might want to adjust your answer to reflect that.

Comment: See my updated question - think you have a import package name clash.

Comment: I changed the package name and it didn't help. I also added some information that might help